# AWX-Ansible with https configuration on centOS 7.x

Tags: ssl, https, docker-compose, ansible-awx

I have installed AWX using docker-compose after cloning version 14.1 on centOS. Followed https://github.com/ansible/awx/blob/devel/INSTALL.md
Default UI is up on port 80.
I am trying to configure it as https accessible. Don't want to use NGINX in front.
I have been going through few blogs but couldn't get much. I have created self-singed certificate and configured in awx inventory, certificate and key , enabling port 443. Docker shows process is up at 80 and 443, but can't access AWX UI.

```
host_port_ssl=443
ssl_certificate=/opt/awx/certs/cert.pem
ssl_certificate_key=/opt/awx/certs/key.pem
docker_compose_dir="~/.awx/awxcompose"
```

Can you please suggest if I am doing correctly.

```
(root@hostname):~/.awx/awxcompose# cat docker-compose.yml
version: '2'
services:

  web:
    image: ansible/awx:14.1.0
    container_name: awx_web
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - postgres
    ports:
      - "443:8053"
      - "80:8052"
    hostname: awxweb
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - supervisor-socket:/var/run/supervisor
      - rsyslog-socket:/var/run/awx-rsyslog/
      - rsyslog-config:/var/lib/awx/rsyslog/
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/SECRET_KEY:/etc/tower/SECRET_KEY"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/environment.sh:/etc/tower/conf.d/environment.sh"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/credentials.py:/etc/tower/conf.d/credentials.py"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:ro"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis_socket:/var/run/redis/:rw"
      - "/opt/awx/certs/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/awxweb.pem:ro"
      - "/opt/awx/certs/key.pem:/etc/nginx/awxweb_key.pem:ro"
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:

  task:
    image: ansible/awx:14.1.0
    container_name: awx_task
    depends_on:
      - redis
      - web
      - postgres
    command: /usr/bin/launch_awx_task.sh
    hostname: awx
    user: root
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - supervisor-socket:/var/run/supervisor
      - rsyslog-socket:/var/run/awx-rsyslog/
      - rsyslog-config:/var/lib/awx/rsyslog/
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/SECRET_KEY:/etc/tower/SECRET_KEY"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/environment.sh:/etc/tower/conf.d/environment.sh"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/credentials.py:/etc/tower/conf.d/credentials.py"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis_socket:/var/run/redis/:rw"
      - "/opt/awx/certs/cert.pem:/etc/nginx/awxweb.pem:ro"
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:
      SUPERVISOR_WEB_CONFIG_PATH: '/etc/supervisord.conf'

  redis:
    image: redis
    container_name: awx_redis
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:
    command: ["/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf"]
    volumes:
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis.conf:/usr/local/etc/redis/redis.conf:ro"
      - "~/.awx/awxcompose/redis_socket:/var/run/redis/:rw"

  postgres:
    image: postgres:10
    container_name: awx_postgres
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ~/.awx/pgdocker/10/data/:/var/lib/postgresql/data:Z
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: awx
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: awxpass
      POSTGRES_DB: awx
      http_proxy:
      https_proxy:
      no_proxy:


volumes:
  supervisor-socket:
  rsyslog-socket:
  rsyslog-config:


CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                         NAMES
81d087f70d27        ansible/awx:14.1.0   "/usr/bin/tini -- ..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        8052/tcp                                      awx_task
f77f731efaa2        ansible/awx:14.1.0   "/usr/bin/tini -- ..."   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes        0.0.0.0:80->8052/tcp, 0.0.0.0:443->8053/tcp   awx_web
076ad0550300        postgres:10          "docker-entrypoint..."   6 days ago          Up 3 minutes        5432/tcp                                      awx_postgres
287cd57a5895        redis                "docker-entrypoint..."   6 days ago          Up 3 minutes        6379/tcp                                      awx_redis
```

Comment: can you also paste the docker-compose?
you can also paste the output of docker ps

Comment: Thanks Taybur for the response. I have updated post with details.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar issue which turned out to be due to my SSL keys having the wrong format. As a result the web server was not starting at all (without any errors in the ansible install script). Check `docker logs awx_web | less` for errors or hints.

Does it run without the SSL configuration? In my case commenting out the SSL settings from the `inventory` and re-running the installer would at least bring up the web server on port 80.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Couldn't find the error details much. so tried upgrading to AWX 15.0.1, solved the issue.